# tkinkter thread not terminating (gif runs in endless loop)

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, gif

I'm trying to link 2 actions with the pressing of a button. I'm using threading
One function 'callback' prints a message, and another one creates a label that
displays a gif animation. When I try to thread them and press the button to run
them, the gif is displayed infinitely (continously), but I'd like to have it 
removed (deleted) from the GUI as soon 'callback' finishes running. Any help is appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import threading
import time

root = Tk()
root.title('Title')

def callback():
     print('this message')
     time.sleep(0.5)

def animate():

    while True:

        try:

            time.sleep(0.04)
            img = PhotoImage(file='path',format="gif - {}".format(num))
            label1 = ttk.Label(root, image=img)
            label1.grid(row=0, column=1)
            num+=1

        except:

            num=0
def thr():

    t1= threading.Thread(target=callback)
    t2= threading.Thread(target=animate)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

button = ttk.Button(root, text='click', command=thr).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
entry = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=30, heigh=10, wrap=WORD)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry.focus()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you could replace image in existing Label instead of creating new Label again and again. Now you have thousands Labels in the same cell - one above another. BTW: `tkinter` has function `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` which you could use instead of  `thread`

Comment: to make code more readable you could put all functions before `root = Tk()`

Comment: how about `if num > 10: break` to leave `while True`  after 10 images and ends thread.

Comment: set image to `None` - `label1['image'] = None` or destroy label - `label1.destroy()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable to inform second thread that first thread ends.

```
running = False
```

But it can be not the best method - maybe you should rather use module `queue` to send information from one thread to another.

You can use `label1.destroy()` to remove label and image but you have to create label only once and later only change image in this label.

```
label1['image'] = img
```

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import threading
import time
#from PIL import Image, ImageTk # for `png`

# --- functions ----

def callback():
    # inform function to use external/global variable because you use `=`
    global running

    print('callback: start')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('callback: end')

    # inform other thread to end running
    running = False

def animate():
    print('animate: start')

    while running:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.04)
            img = PhotoImage(file='path', format="gif - {}".format(num))
            #img = Image.open('test/image-{}.png'.format(num)) # for `png`
            #img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) # for `png`
            #label1.img = img # solution for garbage collector problem # for `png`
            label1['image'] = img
            num += 1
        except:
            num = 0

    #label1.img = None # doesn't work
    #label1['image'] = None # doesn't work

    # destroy label 
    label1.destroy()

    print('animate: end')

def thr():
    # inform function to use external/global variable because you use `=`
    global running
    global label1

    # create new label
    label1 = ttk.Label(root)
    label1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    running = True

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=callback)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=animate)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

# --- main ---

# create global variables
running = False
label1 = None

# - GUI -

root = Tk()
root.title('Title')

button = ttk.Button(root, text='click', command=thr)
button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

entry = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=30, heigh=10, wrap=WORD)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry.focus()
root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** you could also use

```
while t1.is_alive():
```

instead of `while running:`

---

**EDIT:** you can also use `root.after` isntead of second thread.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import threading
import time
#from PIL import Image, ImageTk # for `png`

# --- functions ----

def callback():
    # inform function to use external/global variable because you use `=`
    global running

    print('callback: start')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('callback: end')

def animate(num=0):
    try:
        img = PhotoImage(file='path', format="gif - {}".format(num))
        #img = Image.open('test/ball-{}.png'.format(num)) # for `png`
        #img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) # for `png`
        #label1.img = img # solution for garbage collector problem # for `png`
        label1['image'] = img
        num += 1
    except:
        num = 0

    if t1.is_alive():
        # execute again after 4ms
        root.after(4, animate, num) # 4ms = 0.04s
    else:
        # destroy label 
        label1.destroy()
        print("animate: end")


def thr():
    # inform function to use external/global variable because you use `=`
    global label1
    global t1

    # create new label
    label1 = ttk.Label(root)
    label1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=callback)
    t1.start()

    print("animate: start")
    animate(0)

# --- main ---

# create global variables
label1 = None
t1 = None

# - GUI -

root = Tk()
root.title('Title')

button = ttk.Button(root, text='click', command=thr)
button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

entry = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=30, heigh=10, wrap=WORD)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry.focus()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: hey, thanks! let me try this first thing in the morning and I'll let you know!

Comment: I suspect this may work. will let you know! thank you, really!

Comment: the first code doesnt solve the problem, I keep getting the gif infinite loop, it doesnt destroy itself. the second code doesnt even display the gif. the callback function completes